# Fill in Input Field by Clicking Image (title) with JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, title, fill

My html looks like this

```
<input type="search" id="starSearch" />
<img src="image.png" title="How to do this">
```

How can I change this script that will fill search field with image title attribute value? 
I know this code, but it's for links and innerHTML only

```
 $(function(){
    $('.special_field_link').live('click', function() {
        $("#a_input_id").val($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('img').click(function(){
    $('#starSearch').val($(this).attr('title'));
  })
});​
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gopalrohila/vzZ22/

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
$(document).on("click", "img", function() {
    $("#starSearch").val(this.title);
});
```

Note: don't use `live`, it's deprecated. Use `on` with event delegation.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MqnfB/

Comment: This one works, thank you! 
Now my issue is that jquerytools scrollable isn't working anymore after I included 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<img src="image.png" title="How to do this" id="imgtit">
```

JS

```
   $(function(){
        $('.special_field_link').live('click', function() {
            $("#a_input_id").val($("#imgtit").attr('title'));
        });
    });
```